# Cannot ping Android devices on same wifi network

Tags: wi-fi, networking, nexus-7

I have a Nexus 7 running CyanogenMod 10.1. For some reason I cannot reach it from my laptop on the same wifi network. I cannot ping in either direction. In the past i have been only able to ping one way.

Just tried out on my HTC Sensation and haven't the same issue. Also the Nexus and HTC cant reach each other either.

I have had similar problems with other Android devices. In the past I was developing an app and I could not establish a socket connection from the Android device to my computer. Once I was able to successfully ping the laptop from my device everything worked.

Don't know if it is clear this isn't persistent. In the past I fiddled around and they eventually talked but there was no consistent solution.

I have observed this on 2 different wifi networks.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is quite old now, but I came across this looking to for an answer and managed to work it out myself.

What I did was download a root file explorer (I used Root Browser from JRummy Apps) and navigate to **/proc/sys/net/ipv4** edit **icmp_echo_ignore_all** so that it is a 1-line, 1-character file that simply says **0** (when I opened the file, it was set to 1)

No reboot, ICMP requests started working upon saving. Hope that helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

In wireless Networks settings- check the following:

- Make Sure "Guest Policy" is disabled or Unchecked and
- In Advanced Option: WPA Mode is selected "WPA2 Only and Encryption is selected "AES/CCMP" only

[image]

Comment: how does this work? Any technical background of why this should be causing these obsure issues? Please add an explanation why you think that this would solve this problem - thanks! :)

Comment: Also, wireless settings where? The router? Please clarify.